# How do I install Plugins in NeoVim Correctly

Tags: neovim

Does **NeoVim** have it's own config file just like **vim's** `.vimrc` ? If so where can I get that file in the home directory to make my own custom changes.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Both VIm 8.0 and Neovim have their own built-in package manager.

In **VIm 8.0**, create the following directories:

- `~/.vim/pack/*/start` (where `*` may be any name *e.g.* `~/.vim/pack/jimmy/start`): Clone your required plugin into the `start` directory just as you would if you were installing it for Pathogen. You need nothing more and no commands in your `.vimrc` file.
- `~/.vim/pack/*/opt` (*e.g.* `~/.vim/pack/jimmy/opt`) for plugins that only need to be loaded as required. For colours, add a directory to the `opt` directory and then your colours *e.g.* `~/.vim/pack/jimmy/opt/mycolors/colors/dracula.vim`.

In **Neovim**, the directory structure follows the freedesktop's [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html). Your configuration file is in `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`, but your plugins go into:

- `~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/*/start`

See `:h packages` (VIm 8.0 and Neovim) for more information.

Comment: Neovim's directory structure is a little more longwinded because neovim follows the freedesktop's [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)

Comment: These directories are also specified in the Neovim documentation at [plugins](https://neovim.io/doc/user/usr_05.html#05.6) and [packages](https://neovim.io/doc/user/usr_05.html#05.5).

Comment: It's missing the *plugin* folder: `~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/plugin/*/start`.

Comment: Why is there so much advice out there to install a plugin manager for Neovim if Neovim supports plugins out of the box?

Comment: @Flimm Old habits die hard. Everybody should read `:help packload-two-steps` (and note that dir `pack` is relative to the dirs listed in `set packpath?`).

Comment: @blmayer That is not mentioned in the nvim documentation. Specifically * is allowed, so you can have any number of nested folders presumably, but they wont do anything

Comment: Wow, that is some really bad documentation on (n)vims part. To find out how to install plugins you need to read up on packages, which are defined as bundles of plugins, and extrapolate from their that you can just install single plugins in the same way.

Comment: Note: the plugin files do not go directly into start, but in a folder in start. So in most cases you will extract an archive or `git clone` into start and will end up with something like `~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/PLUGA/start/PLUGA/`. Which is where all the files go.

Comment: Can we also include what's needed to _install_ and _run_ a plugin? Just putting it in the correct folder is not enough, is it?

Answer (score 21):

Neovim config file is named `init.vim`[^1] and its location varies depending on your system:

- *nix and macOS: `$HOME/.config/nvim/init.vim`
- Windows: `~/AppData/Local/nvim/init.vim`

You can also use the command `:echo stdpath('config')` inside neovim to find the config directory.

All your settings can be put into this file if you want to. However, it is often advised to split your config to various files, and then either source those files manually or let Nvim do it for you. An excellent article on how to split your config is [from .vimrc to .vim](https://vimways.org/2018/from-vimrc-to-vim/). You can find my example configuration [here](https://github.com/jdhao/nvim-config) for a reference.

As for installing plugins, it is easy for beginners to use a plugin manager to do all the chores for you. [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) is a good choice. You can use it both on Windows, Linux, and Mac. It is fast and reliable. Follow the documentation of vim-plug to learn how to use it.

Another great plugin manager is [packer.nvim](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim), which is written in Lua and has all the fancy features (lazy loading, pint commits, etc.) you will ever want.

Other plugin managers you may want to try: [dein](https://github.com/Shougo/dein.vim), [minpac](https://github.com/k-takata/minpac).

[1]: for nvim v0.5+, you can also use `init.lua` as your config entry point, see [here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/767cd8b17b71f78bdd4c2e0dd8d3f4f0f1551381).

Comment: Note: [plugpac.vim](https://github.com/bennyyip/plugpac.vim) layers a `vim-plug`-style interface on top of the built-in package manager for better performance than `vim-plug`

Comment: @ssokolow Updated! Though there is no benchmark about plugin manager performance for those plugin managers.

Comment: I was going by the plugpac author's claim in the README that "In my case, it takes 18ms to start up with 53 out 87 plugins loaded(the rest will be load on demand). While vim-plug takes 35ms."

Comment: For windows, I could potentially drop/clone the plugins into the same kind of path for the `init.vim` for NeoVim? `:echo stdpath('config')/pack/name/start/`?

Comment: @Pred, I think you can. For more information, you can read about `:h package` and `:h add-package`.

Answer (score 18):

After two days working on this, dozens of websites gone through, numbing confusion, pulling my hair out, I finally managed to get `plug.vim` working.

The whole secret (buried deep, believe me) is that autoload files in the *missing* autoload directory load *before* the ill-named 'init' file. So, in `~/.config/nvim/` you put `init.vim`, then create an `autoload` directory right beside it *in the same directory*, i.e.:

```
~/.config/nvim/autoload/
```

That is where `plug.vim` goes.  That's right, the `autoload` directory and its contents `plug.vim` does NOT go where the documentation says it should, in `~/local/nvim/site/`.

Then you create some deep hole well away from any of the aforementioned, for instance, `~/.neovim-plugins`, to use for your private, vim-plug-ins directory.  Put the *path* to that that private directory in single quotes `'` inside the parentheses of `plug#begin()` in your init file `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`.

Make sure you uncomment both it as well as `plug#end()` by removing the initial doublequote `"` from their lines. This works on Ubuntu 20.04.

Now, erase the plugins that you have been given (after PLUG) in your init file.  According to the author of vim-plug, these plugins were just 'examples' and you should come up with your own to put after PLUG. I won't go into that, you will be working on that for quite a while.  Try the Rust plugin by the Rust language team, for instance. Man, that is one great language, even better than Java.

Comment: Can you perhaps add a small example plug.vim file?

Answer (score 6):

try `:h init.vim` or `:h vimrc`. You'll see there all the info you're looking for.

Assuming you're on unix machine:
If you still wish this file in you home directory than you may symlink it there with:

```
ln

  Creates links to files and folders.

   - Create a symbolic link to a file (or folder):
     ln -s path/to/file path/to/symlink
```

optionally you may start nvim with the -u flag and tell it what you wish to use as your initialization file, so you can just `nvim -u ~/.vimrc`.
Finally you may add the following in your terminal initialization file(.bashrc/.zshrc or whatever terminal you're using) `alias vim='nvim -u ~/.vimrc'` if you really really want to use this file in your home directory without symlinking it but I wouldn't advice to work this way

Answer (score 5):

I will explain it with itchy/calendar example.

Make a folder in:
~/.config/nvim/pack/

Can be like this:
mkdir ~/.config/nvim/pack/calendar/start/

go to the folder:
cd ~/.config/nvim/pack/calendar/start/

Then clone the repo:
git clone https://github.com/itchyny/calendar.vim.git

Do the config on your init.vim file if needed and it is done!

Answer (score 1):

Neovim uses either vim or lua plugins.

Init config files are located under the ~/.config/nvim directory as:

- init.lua  (holds the 'requires ')
- init.vim  (can reference ~/.vimrc)

Lua config files (*.lua) are usually found in:

~/.config/nvim/lua

Ex. ~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins.lua holds the references to plugins

Vim and lua plugins can be added into the ~/.local directory tree.

From h: add-global-plugin

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nvim/site/plugin

cp /tmp/yourplugin.vim ~/.local/share/nvim/site/plugin
```

Ex.  cp ./termdebug.vim ~/.local/share/nvim/site/plugin/

Restart nvim and termdebug should be available from the command prompt:

:Termdebug

:Termdebugcommand